# How to skip header and footer data in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have first *15 rows* of a excel file as "Header data".
and after *235 rows*, "Footer data".
I need to read data *in between these header and footer data*.

Is there any way to read data into DataFrame by selecting specific range of rows using pandas?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.ExcelFile.parse.html

Comment: Removing Excel tag. This question is not about using Excel.

Comment: @mob You tagged the question with the Excel tag. I removed it.

Answer (score 8):

Demo:

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile(filepath)

# parsing first (index: 0) sheet
total_rows = xl.book.sheet_by_index(0).nrows

skiprows = 15
nrows = 235 - 15

# calc number of footer rows
# (-1) - for the header row
skipfooter = total_rows - nrows - skiprows - 1

df = xl.parse(0, skiprows=skiprows, skipfooter=skipfooter)
```

Comment: kind of, but I need to delete some columns but its showing error: ExcelFile doesn't support del columns

Comment: df=df.take(list(range(18,245))) this worked for me! i dont know how though

Comment: skip_footer is now deprecated, you should use skipfooter intead which accepts as value the number of rows at the end to skip

Comment: @AgustínClemente, thanks for the reminder. I've updated an answer

Comment: @reportgunner, does it make sense now?

Comment: @MaxU cheers, much better now. It was confusing where to put the new value.

Answer (score 6):

You are interested in data from row **15** to row **235**.

You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(somefile.xls)

df = df[15:236] #we have to include row 235
```

Answer (score 6):

So to summarize. Header location is **15** from the top and Footer location is ***Y*** from the bottom. Here's how you import the correct values:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_excel("File.xls",header=15,skipfooter=_Y_)
```

Do ensure that your columnar data isn't being excluded!

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this after loading the file:

```
df=df[(df.index>15)&(df.index<236)]
df.index-=16
```