# How do I exclude header and footer from an excel file in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

`df=pd.read_excel(filename)`

What attributes should I add to exclude header and footer?

Comment: depends. u can use skiprows if u know the line number ur header falls in; pandas will read after that line. for the footer, use skipfooter. Read the [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) for guidance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to skip header and footer data in pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45722949/how-to-skip-header-and-footer-data-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: The part that all of the comments and answers are missing is that Excel format has a header and footer that are part of the page setup and not part of the sheet data. Skiprows and header/footer options to read_excel only deal with the sheet data. The page setup header & footer are what cause warnings when openpyxl is used as the engine for Pandas. To my knowledge there is not a way to pass arguments to the engine (I have read that using a read_only setting in the openpyxl constructor will suppress the warnings) so I am at a loss at how to prevent the warnings..

Answer (score 7):

Head over here: `https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html`

you will find

`pandas.read_excel(io, sheet_name=0, header=0, names=None, index_col=None, usecols=None, squeeze=False, dtype=None, engine=None, converters=None, true_values=None, false_values=None, skiprows=None, nrows=None, na_values=None, keep_default_na=True, verbose=False, parse_dates=False, date_parser=None, thousands=None, comment=None, skipfooter=0, convert_float=True, mangle_dupe_cols=True, **kwds)`

Out of which ones which are useful to you are:

`pandas.read_excel(skiprows=None, skipfooter=0)`

you can specify the value in integer to `skiprows=1` to skip `header` and `skipfooter=1` to skip `footer` you can add as many rows are you want to skip

Hope it helps

Comment: 1. What makes skipfooter necessary if skiprows can be any tuple of rows?
2. For those who struggled with the syntax not being explained or exampled as I did, skiprows doesn't take a list. it will take a tuple, as in (0,1,2). to set a range as a tuple, use range(), like skiprows=range(3). Sadly, the only way to make it simpler with a : is with a callable like it says on the page.

Answer (score 5):

This is how I achieved it:

```
energy = pd.read_excel('Energy Indicators.xls', index_col=None, header=None, footer=None)
energy = energy[18:245].reset_index()
```

I used this for data cleaning in my assignment where I was required to remove header and  footer.

So I first imported raw data from excel using

```
energy = pd.read_excel('Energy Indicators.xls', index_col=None, header=None, footer=None)
```

Now since the row from which actual required data started is 18 and row where footer started is 245 I used this

```
energy = energy[18:245].reset_index()
```

I used `reset_index()` because after removing rows my index was messed up so to reset it.

**You might want to remove that extra column named 'index' which is created by `reset_index()`**

Comment: In case that we are talking about the same datasheet, and has not changed in 2 years:
energy = pd.read_excel('assets/Energy Indicators.xls')
energy = energy[17:244].reset_index()
with you index location 18 you missed the first country and added and empty row after the last country.

Comment: The code which I posted was working absolutely fine because I posted the working code. Still I will check. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

you should create a sun dataframe from previous data frame which doesn't contain the header and footer attribute.

for example,

if you excel file contains 500 rows, in which first three rows are header and last 10 rows are footers then you can do as below:

df = df[4:491]