# Discarding the initial reports in multiple excel and create one dataframe pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

In a folder,there is multiple excel files with initial unwanted report and the unwanted footer also. Unwanted number of header rows are varying in fie to file. I want to create one dataframe by accessing with folder.
Here i attached sample examples.[image]

[image]

This is what i develop so far and want specific method to clean all excel files.

```
cd = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath("D:\project"))

i = 0
dfList = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(cd):
for fname in files:

   
    if re.match("^.*.xlsx$", fname):
        data = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(root, fname)) # want method to clean and read all files at once not file by file
       
        dfList.append(data)    
        i += 1

df = pd.concat(dfList)
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: can this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61004648/how-do-i-exclude-header-and-footer-from-an-excel-file-in-pandas?

Comment: basically use `skiprows=n` to skip n header lines

Comment: Hi antoine
The problem is skiprows=n is varying file to file.In this case it is not constant and want one dataframe by combing all files (Have more files. can't process one by one) also.